# Console Auto Scroll C++

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to disable automatic scrolling in the console with C++? When printing characters closer and closer to the bottom of the console, the console scrolls down making it where the printed character will never reach the bottom.

Comment: No, it's outside of the realm of the language

Comment: Are you looking for something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)?

Comment: So there is no way possible of doing that with Win32 or anything?